# What does the gradient of a graph of 1/current against resistance graph represent?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I did an experiment to investigate how current varied with changing resistance and plotted my results on a graph of 1/current against resistance.The graph is a straight line showing $1/I$ to be directly proportional to $R$. Can somebody please tell me what the gradient of this line represents?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a simple circuit where Ohm's law applies, then we should get

$$V=IR$$

so we see that

$$V/I = R$$

$$1/I=R/V$$

$$1/I = (1/V) \times R$$

The gradient should then be $1/V$. Seems like a slightly bizarre plot but if you got a straight line then that makes the maths simple at least!

Answer (score 2):

For your circuit, $V = I\cdot R$. You are plotting (unusually) R along the X axis and $\frac{1}{I}$ along the Y axis, so the slope is $\frac{1}{V}$.

Now the fact that this slope is a straight line tells you that the voltage is constant. This means that (over the range of your experiment) your voltage source has a low internal resistance.

Imagine for a moment a voltage source with an internal resistance. As you lower the external resistance, the voltage that the source is able to supply will drop; this means that the curve, instead of being a straight line through the original, will rise.

As $R$ becomes smaller, you will eventually reach a point where you "short out" your power supply; the current will no longer scale with $R$ and in fact the curve will intersect the Y axis at some value. This value $y_0$, and the nominal voltage $V$ of the source, can be used to estimate the internal impedance of the voltage supply - it would be

$$R_{i} = V \cdot y_0$$

Alternatively, you could continue the straight line to the point where it intersects the X axis. It will do so at a negative value of R, corresponding to the internal impedance of the voltage source.

Answer (score 0):

It simply mean that when you plot the graph of $1/I$, against $R$, you are going to get a straight line graph. It will cut the y-axis at a certain value. The extrapolate to get the internal resistance, $r$. Gradient of the graph will be1/E. If where it cuts the y-axis is A,then r can be given as, $r=A×1/E$.

Answer (score 0):

$$
I = \frac{E}{R + r}
\\
\frac{1}{I} = \frac{R+r}{E}
\\
\frac{1}{I} = \frac{1}{E} R + \frac{1}{E} r
$$

From the form $y = mx + c$, identify

- $y = 1/I$, independent variable
- $m = 1/E$, slope
- $x = R$, dependent variable
- $r/E = c$, intercept

The slope represents the reciprocal of the EMF of the cell.
Therefore emf, $E = 1/\text{slope}$ measured in volt, V.

Comment: Welcome to our community! Your answer looked okay in the plain-text entry box, but it didn’t interact well with our [formatting language](https://physics.stackexchange.com/editing-help). I’ve [edit]ed it so that it displays correctly.